# Pass data between view controllers is not working correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift5

hope you all are having a great day and staying safe! I am trying to pass data between two view controllers, but it seems like nothing is changing. Here is my for the first View Controller:

```
import UIKit

class AddFoodViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var foodTextField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "toTableViewController") {
            print("hello world")
            let destinationViewController = TableViewController()
            destinationViewController.food.append(foodTextField.text!)
            let homeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TableViewController") as? TableViewController

            view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
        }
    }

}
```

In the second view controller, the array food seems to not change at all, and when i print it it is still empty. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: you create destinationViewController but later use homeViewController instead. I guess you do not need the line with creating destinationViewController. The appending should be  applied to homeViewController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be creating the `destinationViewController` and appending `food` to it, but you're not using it. You need append `food` after you instantiate the `TableViewController`, here's how:

```
var food = [String]()
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "toTableViewController") {
        let homeViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TableViewController") as? TableViewController
        food.append(foodTextField.text!)
        homeViewController.food = food
        view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi frankenstein, this works to some extent, as it just keeps replacing the original value. For example, if I added apples, then the array would become ["Apple"], and then if I added pear, the array would become ["Pear"] instead of ["Pear, Apple"].

Comment: Each time you perform segue you are creating a new VC which has empty foods. You will need to keep array of foods outside your function and set vc.foods = foods after appending to the local food.

Comment: I didn't really understand, how can I keep the array of foods outside of the class?

Comment: Hi frankenstein, this didn't work... I just got the same result, could you help me?

Comment: Are you able to pass data successfully now? If so, close this question and ask another one about appending data between controllers.